# Why is Virtualbox start mode not detachable by default

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

Virtualbox has three start modes:

- normal (with a window for the VM but window cannot be closed)
- headless start (no window for the VM, but you can see a screenshot in VBox UI)
- detachable start (a mix of the above two; window can be closed without turning off VM)

I was wondering, why do they have these three options when the third one satisfies the first and second? Is it possible there are also performance reasons?

In other words, why should I ever need to use the other options?

Comment: IIRC these options are relatively new.

Comment: at my host ubuntu16.04 screen of the vm turns black when windows is starting. Probably at the time, windows loads some graphics.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can read why in the current version of the [user manual for the `startvm` command](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-startvm):

> Starts a VM with detachable UI (technically it is a headless VM with user interface in a separate process). This is an experimental feature as it lacks certain functionality at the moment (e.g. 3D acceleration will not work).

So, yes, this is still a new feature and it is missing some of the features a fully attached GUI provides.

Comment: Is this answer still up-to-date ? I'm guessing things changed since 2016

Comment: @Magix A [post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=99609#p483370) from September 2020 suggests that 3D acceleration still doesn't work in detached/headless mode.

Answer (score 15):

(Not enough reputation to comment here, so apologies for the "new answer" instead)

This isn't an option in the UI, but [is an option in the command line tool](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=90503).

`VBoxManage modifyvm "vmname" --defaultfrontend headless`

- Sets the VM named "vmname" to headless start if you just click the big green Start button

`VBoxManage modifyvm "vmname" --defaultfrontend separate`

- Sets the VM named "vmname" to detachable start if you just click the big green Start button

`VBoxManage modifyvm "vmname" --defaultfrontend gui`

- Resets the VM named "vmname" to the default integrated (non-detachable) GUI start if you just click the big green Start button

Comment: The options are also available in the VirtualBox Manager UI, in the "Show" (green arrow) dropdown box.

Comment: Works! -> to get the list of vms:  VBoxManage list vms

Comment: This is useful if you have a group of VMs you want to start, but don't want them all to start in GUI mode. Thanks :)